# What is the command to close a single tab in Sublime?

Tags: tabs, sublimetext

Cmd-shift-w closes the whole window.  I want to just close out a single tab. How do I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Mac:** cmd + w

**Windows**: ctrl + w

**Linux** : ctrl + w

Comment: ctrl + f4 is also an alternative way for the Windows

Answer (score 2):

Hit ctrl+f4 to close a single tab.

To make extra sure go to "Preferences" > "Key Bindings - Default". A file will open displaying the default shortcuts. Search for :

> "command": "close_file"

to see your default binding.

Comment: Thanks. I bind ctrl+w to delete line so for me, it's more useful to check the current binding in preferences. For me ctrl+F4 is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the operating system you're using...

On a mac it's Apple(cmd)+W

Answer (score 0):

This is too old to answer but just in case someone wants to only close a tab/file and do nothing if there is no tab/file open. Just add the following settings to your keybindings.

```
{ "keys": ["super+w"], "command": "close_file" }
```

So instead of `close`, use `close_file`.